# Cardano NFT Fetching From Collection

Tags: cryptography, blockchain, nft, cardano

How can one obtain the NFTs associated with a particular user's Cardano wallet address? The Policy ID is used to represent a collection. So, from that specific collection, how can one filter the NFTs by wallet address? We only need to retrieve the assets associated with a particular wallet address. Any ideas?

Does anyone know of any methods to accomplish this?